# Como Filtrar valores específicos com Excel e adiciona-los em outra tabela?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Queria filtrar apenas as letras "A" da tabela a esquerda e adicionar na tabela a direita, trazer todas as Letras "A" para a tabela a direita, de acordo com a quantidade que cada coluna(1 2 3) que contenha a letra "A", ??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Coloque em `J3`:

```
=SE(F3='A';'A';'')
```

Replique para as demais células.

Comment: Favor ler [como formatar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas)

Comment: Lucas Augusto Coelho Lopes, teria como colocar uma letra em baixo da outra? porque nesse caso as letras ficaram separadas conforme a tabela da esquerda

Comment: Não entendi, como assim, @ElienayJunior?

Comment: Na coluna de número 1 ficaria a letra "A" em cada linha sem apresentar as células em branco

Comment: Letra "A" em baixo de "A"

Comment: do mesmo jeito que vc replicou a fórmula para a direita, também pode replicar para baixo, se é isso que eu entendi.

Comment: Eu estou dizendo, sem apresentar as colunas em branco, de F3=A, F4=A e F5=A, entendeu??

Comment: um em baixo do outro sem dar espaços

Comment: Aí eu já não sei

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tenta assim:

Na célula: `J3`

Insira a fórmula: `=SE(CONT.SE(F:F;"A")-LIN()+3>0;"A";"")`

Depois arrasta para baixo e para os lados, à vontade!

Comment: Não deu certo, ele deixou todas as células em branco, logo depois eu retirei  "+3>0" e ele jogou a letra "A" em todas as células, quando deveria apenas jogar a quantidade de "A" certa referente a tabela da esquerda

Comment: Fica um pouco ruim, deixar todas as linhas da coluna de "F" selecionadas, pois se tiver algum conteúdo em cima ou em baixo nas células, ele tbm vai fazer a contagem

Comment: Fiz com +3 pois imaginei dos seus dados estarem na linha 3. Qual linha estão. Dê um exemplo do resultado que você quer, tira print.. assim fica mais fácil elaborar uma solução.

Comment: Eles estavam, mas não estão mais. Eu desloquei a tabela para outro local

Comment: Na coluna 1 tem que ficar três letras "A" uma em baixo da outra sem apresentar linhas vazias(Células em branco) e assim por diante